# Google calendar free/busy still contains creator email

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a google calendar (it is a room resource) that I plan to allow public read access to, but only allow free/busy information. However, when I share the calendar link, and look at the data fetched for events, the response still contains the email of the event creator, should this information not also be hidden for public access, when calendar is free/busy read only?

Below is an example of the response the calendar gets from google:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"###\"",
 "summary": "summary",
 "updated": "2023-05-29T17:46:22.570Z",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin",
 "accessRole": "freeBusyReader",
 "defaultReminders": [],
 "nextSyncToken": "###",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3371263293462000\"",
   "id": "###",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?...",
   "updated": "2023-05-29T07:25:46.731Z",
   "creator": {
    "email": "creator@at-my-domain.org"
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2023-06-07T09:30:00+02:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2023-06-07T10:30:00+02:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen"
   },
   "visibility": "private",
   "iCalUID": "###@google.com"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: The creators name will always be in the list of attendees the need to be there to accept people when they join

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo - but this is the request made for a calendar, that is made public with only busy/free information - it is not possible to react on the events, only read them, so why the need for the creator email, as this is pure busy/free information - for my point of view this is sensitive information that i don't want to share for this type of calendar

Comment: just because a calendar is public doesn't mean it doesn't have an owner.   When an event is created it also has an owner or creator if you will.